# North/South/East/West coordinate in postgis to use with st_contains

Tags: postgis

Im getting boundaries from google map, with north/south/east/west coordinates.

Now I want to find all my points there are within these coordinates.

```
ST_Contains(
    ST_MakeEnvelope(:west, :south, :east, :north, 4326)
    ST_Transform(mypoints, 4326)
)
```

Now this doesnt work always.

Fx with

```
North: 25.784574189277627
West: -34.802203056636074
East: -169.80220305663607
South: -64.78137453669326
```

Which should give me some results.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In PostGIS a polygon bigger than half the world is treated as it's opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737506/in-postgis-a-polygon-bigger-than-half-the-world-is-treated-as-its-opposite)